# SQL Unit Testing Creating test for Stored procedure that does not necessarily return a value

Tags: sql, t-sql, unit-testing

I am new to sql unit testing but I have written my first test and trying to make sure this is a sensible test. So I have a stored procedure that does a simply Update(if exists) or insert(if not exists). Using TSQLUnit, I wrote the test below to test my stored procedure called **spModifyData**. What the test is designed to do is verify that when an existing ID is passed, a new record is not created in the database.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ut_TestspModifyData] 
AS
BEGIN 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
     -- Setup the test conditions by inserting test data
     DECLARE 
                @newidone uniqueidentifier,
                @newidtwo uniqueidentifier,
                @newidthree uniqueidentifier,
                @ExpectedID uniqueidentifier,
                @ActualID uniqueidentifier

                SET @ActualID = '13E7C741-9A04-4E84-B604-141874A6A9B4'
                SET @ExpectedID = '13E7C741-9A04-4E84-B604-141874A6A9B4'
                SET @newidone = newID()
                SET @newidtwo = newID()
                SET @newidthree = newID()

                 INSERT INTO DataSource( [DataSourcePrimarySource],[DataSourceName],[DataSourceRecordCreateDate] 
          ,[DataSourceStatus] ,[DataSourceIsActive]) VALUES ('PRIMARY SOURCE ONE', 'XYZ', GETDATE() , @newidone, 1)

  -- Exercise the test
 EXEC  spModifyDataSource @ActualID , 'PRIMARY SOURCE ONETWO', 'BBB', @newIDone, 0  

 -- Assert expectations
 IF (@ExpectedID != @ActualID)
                EXEC dbo.tsu_Failure 'ModifyData failed.' 

-- Teardown
 -- Implicitly done via ROLLBACK TRAN

END
```

Comment: what is really expected?

Comment: I expect that no insert will be made and that the ActualID will equal expectedID

Answer (score 0):

As this test is testing a functional part of your stored procedure, then yes it is a "sensible" unit test - it doesn't have to test parameters to be valid.

That being said - I'm not sure it's the best way of testing what you are trying to. You appear to be using `@ActualID` as a variable which you set early on but don't specify as an `OUTPUT` parameter, so I would always expect this test to pass (either I'm reading that wrong, or there's a bug in the test).

Your question stated your test aim was : "verify that when an existing ID is passed, **a new record is not created in the database.**"

I would actually approach the assert section of this test slightly differently - I'd check the result in the `DataSource` table directly rather than checking the returned parameter - as you are then checking what's created in the database. I would additionally check any output parameter, but usually I'd regard output parameters as a separate test to data checks, or at least a separate assert - and therefore separate message - in the test.

I think you will find it helpful if you can use more descriptive messages - as per the example in [the TSQLUnit cookbook](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/tsqlunit/wiki/CookBook)

I find it easier to resolve tests that only test one thing - and therefore I know what needs to be fixed. They are often simpler to write, too!

Does that help?

Comment: So you suggest that the @ActualID be an OUTPUT parameter from my stored procedure. How do I check the result in the datasource table directly and link whatever is returned to this particular test?

Comment: You're using @ActualID in the test like it is an output parameter - but not actually calling it as such.. That means that your assert would always be true (as your SP wouldn't alter the parameter). In terms of checking the result in the datasource table directly, you need to essentially do a select from the destination table (Datasource?) into some result variables and compare those with what is expected (i.e. what you supplied as input parameters to the SP). Call dbo.tsu_Failure if they don't match. That way you're testing what the SP has done, not merely what it's told you it has done.